# SSMS 2008 not remembering connection login credentials

Tags: ssms, password-management

When connecting to a server on SQL Server Management Studio 2008, I'm entering the `Server Name`, and using `SQL Server Authentication`, entering `Login` & `Password`, and ticking `Remember password`.

However, next time I open SSMS, the server name has been remembered in the drop down, but the login and password have been forgotten.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does remembers it sometimes (I could not figure out what the rule is) but not always.

That's what I do (I have 8 different servers entered like that):

1. in SSMS -> View | Registered Servers
2. Choose "Database Engine" (should be selected by default)
3. Right click on "Local Server Groups" and choose "New Server Registration" (or create your own group first if you prefer)
4. Enter all required details: Server address, user name, password, tick "Remember password" box, Registered server name
5. Click "OK" -- now you can always connect to this server from this "Registered Servers" tool window - it will not ask for a password again.

Comment: Sweet! Cheers @LazyOne this will save me loads of time!